# Django - Query by foreign key in views

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am trying to make a button on the post that when a user cliks on it, is requesting to be added to the post as an attendance and then, the author of the post has to approve that request.

**Models.py**

```
class Attending(models.Model):
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    attending = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='user_event_attending')
```

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attending = models.ForeignKey(Attending, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='atending', null=True)
```

My problem here is that every time I writte a query for the button is giving me erros and I couldn`t figure it out how to get the reverse of the foreign key.

This is my code on my **views.py**

```
def request_event(request, pk):
    previous = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    try:
        query = Attending.objects.get(pk=pk)
        request_attending = query.post_set.add(request.user)
        messages.success(request, f'Request sent!')
        return redirect(previous)
    except query.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('/')
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you share the errors? Also you are adding `request.user` which is a user object to `post_set`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `query.post_set` is just relationship. You cannot call method `add` just like that. You can add to `ManyToMany` relation and I believe you want to add user to `Attending.attending` field, not directly to `Post` object. Change that to:

```
...
query = Attending.objects.get(pk=pk)
query.attending.add(request.user)
messages.success(request, f'Request sent!')
....
```

| Update |

I think you should consider rearraning your relationships. If I understand your plan, you should go this way:

```
class Attending(models.Model):
    ...
    attendant = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='events_attending', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For one `Post` object there can be many `Attending` objects, then you can use relations like that:

```
att = Attending.objects.first()
att.post                         # get related Post object from ForeignKey | there is only one

post = Post.objects.first()
post.attending_set.all()         # get all related Attending objects

Post.objects.get(attending=att)  # get Post object that the Attending object have in ForeignKey field

user = User.objects.first()
user.post_set.all()              # get all Post objects that User is author in
user.events_attending.all()      # get all related Attending objects
```

For more check [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#relationships).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks good but how can I reference that to an specific post? Thats why I was trying to bring the post PK.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think you should think about rebuilding your structure a bit :)

Comment: So cool!! And the query for the button to add it to the post, will be the same?

Comment: Slightly different. I'll give you chance to try it for yourself, but ping me here if you create another question with a new approach and I'll try to help.

Comment: Mmm if you can guide me I will be gratefull with your help... im super stuck with this

Comment: Ok, sure. If a `request.user` clicks on a button, you have to create new `Attending` object with `request.user` as `attendant` and `Post.objects.get(pk=pk)` as `post`. So basically something like: `Attending.objects.create(post=pk, attendant=request.user)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @NixonSparrow ! This is giving me an error: "Cannot assign "431": "Attending.post" must be a "Post" instance".

Comment: You cannot pass string as pk, it has to be an integer. If it will not work, pass there `post=Post.objects.get(pk=int(pk))`.

Comment: mmm tried that but is giving same error. Now on the second line:

post = Post.objects.get(pk=int(pk))
Attending.objects.create(post=pk, attendant=request.user)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242410/discussion-between-nixonsparrow-and-chrislumber).